# Concat numbers to write to file by printWriter

Tags: java, file, printwriter

I wanted an output like:

```
 9000000000
 9000000001
 9000000002
 ...
 9999999999
```

I started loop from a=9 but it printing from starting output it gives into the file starting from 0 to 9 and the continuing one by one.

```
class Demo {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    long n = 9;
    int a = 9, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0, g = 0, h = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("psy.txt", "UTF-8");

    for (a = 9; a <= n; j++) {
      for (b = 0; b <= n; i++) {
        for (c = 0; c <= n; j++) {
          for (d = 0; d <= n; i++) {
            for (e = 0; e <= n; j++) {
              for (f = 0; f <= n; i++) {
                for (g = 0; g <= n; j++) {
                  for (h = 0; h <= n; i++) {
                    for (i = 0; i <= n; j++) {
                      for (j = 0; j <= n; i++) {
                        writer.println(a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j);
                        System.out.println(a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i
                            + j);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    writer.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: copy paste error? You don't increment a, b, c... it's always i or j

Comment: `System.out.println(a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j);` there is one number. You don't want it, do you?

Comment: yes but i wanted is to, when i execute this program, a file with "psy.txt" should have value from 9000000000 but it start from 0

Comment: All initial values are zero. How do you want it to be 9000000000 at start?

Comment: @DariushJafari, a = 9

Comment: you haven't got my question. I request you to copy the code and run it, you will get what i wanted to ask

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concat numbers this way. You need to convert them to `String' in order to concat them. Besides your loop incrementors are wrong. All of them have i++ and j++ !!!!!

```
 for (a = 9; a <= n; a++) {
        for (b = 0; b <= n; b++) {
            for (c = 0; c <= n; c++) {
                for (d = 0; d <= n; d++) {
                    for (e = 0; e <= n; e++) {
                        for (f = 0; f <= n; f++) {
                            for (g = 0; g <= n; g++) {
                                for (h = 0; h <= n; h++) {
                                    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
                                        for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
                                            String s = a + "" + b + "" + c + "" + d + "" + e + "" + f + "" + g + "" + h + "" + i + "" + j;
                                            writer.println(s);
                                            System.out.println(s);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You want to write numbers one by one starting from 9000000000. A solution is :

```
 for (long l = 9000000000L; l < 9999999999L; l++) {
        writer.println(l);
        System.out.println(l);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but its printing now 14 digit value

Comment: you aren't right, it's too large for integer numbers.

Comment: The loop variable is long not integer